# speech to text not works on ubuntu's browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, microphone, text-to-speech

I've to start a project that will include the "speech to text" feature. So i start to check what is available around, and I found this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API

the first one demo is that one: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

The demo seem to works and ask to take the control over the mic. i try it over chromium 67.0.3396.99, I can hit the mic button but it remain active just for a second and no way to talk... permission on chrome seems ok to me... not workin at all over firefox.

and this: https://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

The second demo is that one: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/speech-input/index.html

but only a text field is showed to me! Even on firefox, the webkit seems not supported at all.

these are the mic settings over chromium, NB skype calls over web browser works!!!

[mic's settings on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i16Tp.png)

how can I solve this type of issue?

Comment: these are demos for google's api speech to text, i need to develop a project with this api. But if   can't even runs demos the road will be so rocky...